# Grails criteria opposite of 'ilike'

Tags: grails

When defining search criteria, what is the syntax for 'is not equal to'? (I want to include case insensitivity) so I guess another way is to ask what would be the opposite of:

```
ilike("holderFirstName", "Steph%")
```

? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also negate the clause using `not`-statement

```
not{
  ilike "holderFirstName", "Steph%"
}
```

Comment: That may or may not work, depending on which GORM implementation is being used.  I expect it to work with Hibernate and I expect it to not work with mongo.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25124899/query-condition-cannot-be-negated.